# Restangular post in loop

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I need to call a list of restangular.post inside of a loop, to add many user (for example)

I have a factory that do something like that:

```
createUser (user) {
return Restangular.all(URL).post(user);
}
```

then in controller In need to call this factory inside of a loop:

```
for( var us in users){
createUser(us);
}
```

the problem is that I cant do this! it add always only the last user object!, so how to do $q.all() using Restangular, or there are any other solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var promises = [];
for (var us in users) {
promises.push(Restangular.all(URL).post(us);
}
$q.all(promises).then(function (responses) {
// responses is an array with one return value per request made
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem is too small.

The problem is that you call the createUser function inside a loop. So your loop continues to execute but Post request not gets fulfilled. And hence your last user object get saved only.

**So what you can do:**

You have to make **recursive function** where when your first objects get saved then call the same function with the second object and so on.

OR

You can try with **Callback function**. Please read first how callback function works.

**Here i used a callback function. May be this help you.**

```
function createUser(userObject, cb){
  Restangular
  .all(URL)
  .post(user)
  .then(function (response){
     if(response){
       cb(null, response); //user created.. now callback the function
     }else{
       cb(err, 'error occured');
     }
  })
  .catch(function(ex){
    //something bad happened...
  })
}

var index = 0;
function save(){
 if(users.length != index + 1){
  createUser(users[index], function(data){
    console.log(data);  //this is saved data which is return by callback
    index++;
  });
 }
}
```

now you need to call save function only. Here users is a array which contains all users object.

Comment: I updated the answer with the code. And I used the callback function.